# How call arguments stack works in Python?

Tags: python, stack, callstack

I am learning python and trying to get idea how stack works in python.  I have some doubts. I know how stack work and i have read many articles and tutorials about it. I have read many threads on stackoverflow they are all good, still I have some doubts.

As far I have read stack stores and return values of function. It work by LIFO principal.

Only first value of the stack will return and store at top.

So my question is - suppose there are four variables:

```
a = 9
b = 2
c = 13
d = 4
```

They are stored in stack in order in which function call the value, for example:

```
sum = a + d
sum = b + c

a = 9
d = 4
b = 2
c = 13
```

and they will return from top to bottom. Now my confusion is - if any operation requires to use `d` and `c`, while stack return values from the top, how stack will get the values `d` and `c`, as long as they are in middle of stack. Will stack first return a and then return d ??

That's the confusion.

Comment: There is no `push`ing or `pop`ing involved when accessing stack-variables.

Comment: I am confused, do you mean "stack" as a data structure or "stack" as memory? If the first one is the case -- don't use it if you will need values NOT from top, if the latter, the variables are within the "virtual" heap of the stacked function, so it is fine

Comment: Why did you tag this with [stack-overflow]?

Comment: Have you tried running some code in an interpreter? That's not how any of this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested how python works under the hood, there is a standard CPython library [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html).
Here is the output for your test code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test():
...     a = 9
...     b = 2
...     c = 13
...     d = 14
...     sum1 = a + d
...     sum2 = b + c
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (9)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (13)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  5          18 LOAD_CONST               4 (14)
             21 STORE_FAST               3 (d)

  6          24 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             27 LOAD_FAST                3 (d)
             30 BINARY_ADD          
             31 STORE_FAST               4 (sum1)

  7          34 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             37 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             40 BINARY_ADD          
             41 STORE_FAST               5 (sum2)
             44 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             47 RETURN_VALUE
```

and it has nothing to do with stack as you can see.
It won't do even with adjusted code, like

```
>>> def test2(a,b,c,d):
...     sum1 = a + d
...     sum2 = b + c
... 
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                3 (d)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 STORE_FAST               4 (sum1)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             13 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             16 BINARY_ADD          
             17 STORE_FAST               5 (sum2)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you're interested in stack concept in general in computing, you should switch to some low-level (2.5 generation languages, like C), or go even deeper to assembly languages.

Reading about various calling conventions may be another good start point as well ( [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for example )

Comment: its callling value by reference ? like LOAD_FAST call 0(a) so is 0 memory adress ?

Comment: it's index of variable in Python stack frame. Despite it's called _stack_ frame, you should think of it more like x86/ARM general purpose registers (i.e eax, ebx / r0, r1, r2 et cetera).
Frame is allocated within stack of CPython virtual machine (thus _stack frame_), but the data is not accessed in LIFO order.
Here is [bytecodes reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#bytecodes) for CPython

Comment: when python variable (not some const value) is pushed on stack, then yes, you can say it's accessed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Although stacks work as a LIFO, you have to be careful about exactly which data structures are being stacked. For instance, many programming languages use a stack to store parameters and local variables when calling a function. But the thing that is being stacked is the entire call frame, not the individual variables in the frame.

In C, for instance, I may have local variables a, b, c, d "on the stack" but that means that they are stored at a known fixed offset from the start of the frame. The variables can be accessed in any order and they don't move around (apart from optimizations the compiler may be doing).

Python makes it a bit more complicated. In CPython at least, there is a stack frame under the covers, but the local variables you see are actually stored in an an array (see shadowranger's note below)  on a function instance object which makes up the function's local namespace. All variables can be accessed through the dict at any time.

In these cases, the local variables are not themselves a LIFO and can be accessed arbitrarily as long as you know their offset or name in the namespace dict.

Comment: Local variables aren't actually stored in a `dict` automatically. `locals()` (and possibly closure nested access?) has to make a `dict` on demand, if you never call it though, the local variables are stored in an array. If you use `dis`, you'll see the difference; locals are accessed with `LOAD_FAST`/`STORE_FAST` which looks in an array indexed by number (the size of the array is determined by the compiler, with names assigned to numbers). Using a `dict` for local access would be far too slow.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - thanks! I updated referencing your comment. I always assumed locals and, say, class instance method lookups were roughly equivalent.